# Xamarin forms: Issue with epubreader.cross

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am using [epubreader.cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) NuGet package for parsing .epub files.

My Code:

```
string fileName = "SampleEPUB.epub";
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
```

For some .epb files I am getting below exceptions:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Incorrect EPUB navigation page target: normal is incorrect value for page target type.)'

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Incorrect EPUB spine: TOC is missing)'
```

All my .epub files are able to view using Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11. So what will be the reason behind this issue?

I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXBcF6a9vr8yfCwykK7fe8u_nj6IHEtI/view?usp=sharing) having .epub files for the reference.

Comment: the project you linked to has not been updated in 3 years and includes this note in its README - "The project is deprecated'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That project seems to be deprecated. However , it looks like that the root repo is active though . You could check the [github project site](https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader) .

You need to download the dll file manually from this [link](https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader#download-latest-stable-release) , choose the  `for .NET Standard` one . Then add the dll file into forms project , just right click `Dependencies - Add project reference - Browse - Select the download file`

Comment: Or you could convert the epub to pdf firstly in server .

Comment: Did you check the demo provided by Cole ?https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183588/xamarin-forms-issue-with-epubreader-cross

Comment: You could post the issue to https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader/issues .

Comment: Posted an issue on Github https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader/issues/33. I am accepting your answer, if you find any better solution, please let me know. Thanks for the support.

Comment: No comment from Github for this issue. Any better solution?  Is there any other NuGet package for parsing the epub files? Still, I have the same issue.