# Xamarin forms: Issue with epubreader NuGet Package

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am using [epubreader](https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader) **(vers-one)** NuGet package for parsing .epub files.

My Code:

```
string fileName = "SampleEPUB.epub";
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
foreach (EpubNavigationItem chapter in epubBook.Navigation)
{
    chapterDetails.Add(new ChapterDetails() { title = chapter.Title, htmlData = chapter.HtmlContentFile?.Content, subChapters = chapter.NestedItems });
}
```

**1 When parsing the epub file like above, I am getting only one chapter(chapter name is content). If I click that chapter there is no data.**

2 When we open that epub files using Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11, there are a lot of chapters and contents. I need to parse all the chapters and TOC in the epub file.  Please help me to find the issue behind this.

3 Also tried [epubreader.cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) NuGet package, but that project is [deprecated](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross#note-the-project-is-deprecated-cause-parent-repo-already-supports-net-standart-and-this-one-is-not-going-to-be-maintained). Are there any other NuGet packages for parsing epub files?

4 Currently, I have added sample epub files to the project and implemented parsing for it. Instead of that if the epub file is a [link](http://catholic-brain.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2020/07/21/08/58/27/496/head/Alices-Adventures-in-wonderland.epub) how I can manage it?

I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BTCHjU3_I7--wjBPQKkVh0XTwphOCZOL/view?usp=sharing) having .epub files for the reference. I have already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845727/xamarin-forms-issue-with-epubreader-cross) related to this, but it not solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

Since it works in **Adobe Digital Editions 4.x.x** , we could install the plugin to our application .

Adobe Mobile SDK is no longer available in the Xamarin Components Store or in the NuGet Gallery. To download the Xamarin components, we need to go to [GitHub](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services) download it directly.

#### Android

Import the **ADBMobile** Component to your Xamarin.Android Project:

1. Open your Xamarin Project
2. Open References dialog, and then .Net Assembly tab.
3. Select ADBMobile.XamarinAndroidBinding.dll from the folder lib/Android.
4. Add your ADBMobileConfig.json file into the Assets folder of your project.
5. Add permissions for:

• INTERNET
• ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Add the following activity and receiver if you are using In-app messaging:

```
<activity
android:name="com.adobe.mobile.MessageFullScreenActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<receiver android:name="com.adobe.mobile.MessageNotificationHandler" />
```

Add the following receiver if you are using acquisition:

```
<receiver android:name="com.your.package.name.GPBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

#### iOS

Import the ADBMobile Component to your Xamarin.iOS Project:

1. Open your Xamarin Project.
2. Open References dialog, and then .Net Assembly tab.
3. Select ADBMobile.XamarinIOSBinding.dll from the folder lib/ios-unified.
4. Add your ADBMobileConfig.json file to the project.

You could check the [docs](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/xamarin/xamarin.pdf) for more details .

Comment: I got the `ADBMobileConfig.json` files. But I don't know from where I can get the .dll files.

Also, I didn't get the 2nd step. For the android and ios project we have a References folder, but I didn't see any .Net Assembly tab.

![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/bu/e7nmf6yyt79y.png "")

Comment: Could you please provide the android and ios dll file links?

Comment: I have downloaded the latest android and ios SDK from [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/releases).  `ADBMobileConfig.json` files are available on that SDK but dll files are not available. 

After adding the dll files and JSON files how I can open an epub book using this?

Comment: Why don’t you have a try firstly?

Comment: I am trying to install the plugin, but the dll files are not found, also the second step of ADBMobile component import. Usually, I am installing the NuGet packages, this is the first time I am dealing with dll files.

Comment: You could refer the sample from  https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/tree/master/sdks/Xamarin/ADBMobile/samples

Comment: For android, I have added the dll files and JSON files. How can I open an epub file using this?

Comment: Could you please implement the solution on the sample project I have uploaded and share it with me? I am really stuck on this.

Comment: Did you check the code from https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/blob/master/sdks/Xamarin/ADBMobile/samples/iOSSample/iOSSample/AdobeMobileSampleViewController.cs